# How to install debug symbol for OpenMPI on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mpi

I couldn't find debug symbol in the official repo:

```
$ apt-cache search openmpi
gromacs-openmpi - Molecular dynamics sim, binaries for OpenMPI parallelization
libblacs-openmpi1 - Basic Linear Algebra Comm. Subprograms - Shared libs. for OpenMPI
libhdf5-openmpi-10 - Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - runtime files - OpenMPI version
libhdf5-openmpi-10-dbg - Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - OpenMPI Debug package
libhdf5-openmpi-dev - Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - development files - OpenMPI version
libmeep-lam4-8 - library for using parallel (OpenMPI) version of meep
libmeep-lam4-dev - development library for using parallel (OpenMPI) version of meep
libmeep-mpi-default-dev - development library for using parallel (OpenMPI) version of meep
libmeep-mpi-default8 - library for using parallel (OpenMPI) version of meep
libmeep-mpich2-8 - library for using parallel (OpenMPI) version of meep
libmeep-mpich2-dev - development library for using parallel (OpenMPI) version of meep
libmeep-openmpi-dev - development library for using parallel (OpenMPI) version of meep
libmeep-openmpi8 - library for using parallel (OpenMPI) version of meep
libopenmpi-dev - high performance message passing library -- header files
libopenmpi1.10 - high performance message passing library -- shared library
libscalapack-openmpi1 - Scalable Linear Algebra Package - Shared libs. for OpenMPI
libtachyon-openmpi-0 - Parallel/Multiprocessor Ray Tracing Library - runtime - OpenMPI flavour
libtachyon-openmpi-0-dbg - Parallel/Multiprocessor Ray Tracing Library - debug package - OpenMPI flavour
libtachyon-openmpi-0-dev - Parallel/Multiprocessor Ray Tracing Library - development - OpenMPI flavour
libtachyon-serial-0 - Parallel/Multiprocessor Ray Tracing Library - runtime - serial flavour
likwid - toolsuite for performance oriented programmers
meep-lam4 - software package for FDTD simulation, parallel (OpenMPI) version
meep-mpi-default - software package for FDTD simulation, parallel (OpenMPI) version
meep-mpich2 - software package for FDTD simulation, parallel (OpenMPI) version
meep-openmpi - software package for FDTD simulation, parallel (OpenMPI) version
mpqc-openmpi - Massively Parallel Quantum Chemistry Program (OpenMPI transitional package)
netpipe-openmpi - Network performance tool using OpenMPI
openmpi-bin - high performance message passing library -- binaries
openmpi-common - high performance message passing library -- common files
openmpi-doc - high performance message passing library -- man pages
relion-bin+mpi - parallel toolkit for 3D reconstructions in cryo-electron microscopy
yorick-full - full installation of the Yorick interpreter and add-ons
yorick-mpy-openmpi - Message Passing Yorick (OpenMPI build)
zalign - parallel local alignment of biological sequences
```

Do I have to manually install debug symbol from source? I found some related package [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openmpi/1.10.2-8ubuntu1). It looks like they are from the official repo. But why are they not displayed in `apt-cache`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [special repository](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages) with debug packages:

```
echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs) main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed main restricted universe multiverse" | \
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 428D7C01 C8CAB6595FDFF622

sudo apt-get update
```

Then install debug packages:

```
sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin-dbgsym
```